# API for historical traffic data?

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, traffic

Does anyone know of a public API for historical traffic data?

Some quick googling pulls up an API from Yahoo which offers real-time data, but I'd be curious if anyone hosts a service for historical data - i.e., what was the "severity" (one of the attributes the Yahoo API returns) for a given location at a given date and time.

*(I'm going to guess that such a thing doesn't exist today, or at least no public options, as this would be an immense amount of data to store, but it never hurts to ask...)*

Comment: Didn't Google implement a historical driving traffic option on maps?

Answer (score 5):

While yahoo has shut down its traffic apis, there are a number of companies providing traffic information.

- [HERE](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic) from Nokia
- [Traffic API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441725.aspx) from Microsoft
- [Traffic API](https://developer.mapquest.com/products/traffic) from MapQuest
- [Predictive Traffic API](http://inrix.com/resources/dev-zone/) from INRIX

Answer (score 0):

These guys certainly have the data, but I don't know how easy it is to get access to the API: http://inrix.com/developers