# getting historical data from google maps traffic

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to get historical data for the traffic layer in google maps, i.e. specify a time and location and receive whether traffic was normal or slow etc? I don't need the typical traffic conditions given a time and day, I need concrete data as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Some APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32008512/203172) provide historical data only for traffic incidents like congestion and accidents.