# How to get average traffic data on google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to show average traffic layer on google map like this.

[image: example snippet]

But, this map shows the real time data of traffic, instead i want to show average traffic over some period of time on google map, is it possible? or any other maps api can help?

> Please star this issue [issue tracker link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829567) to vote and get update for this feature.

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 7):

If you check the Google Maps [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#TrafficLayer), the only information that you can find here about traffic is the [Traffic Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/trafficlayer). But this traffic layer add a real-time traffic information(if supported) in your maps. But on the [Google Maps website](https://www.google.com.ph/maps), there is a [typical traffic](https://maps.googleblog.com/2008/04/new-ways-to-beat-traffic-with-google.html) that you can use to see the information about traffic in any given day and time.

But I think this typical traffic is not yet available in Google Maps API. So what can I suggest you is to make a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=traffic&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Stars+ApiType+Internal&cells=tiles) about this information.

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104853/api-for-historical-traffic-data/32008512#32008512) if it can help you to your problem.