# How to do research on traffic jam with Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

Is it possible to research traffic jam, with help of Google API? e.g. For one month "look" at data from Google traffic jam and to find most overcrowded parts of the city.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get average traffic data on google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490696/how-to-get-average-traffic-data-on-google-map)

Answer (score 1):

You can try generating routes at different times of day across the city using the Directions API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

But AFAIK there is no API for comprehensive traffic data.

Comment: anyone know if this has changed since the posts above?